# Tomcat Application Lifetime

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm building a java web application and hosting it in Tomcat. I have some prior experience with IIS. I want to know about application lifetime in Tomcat.
For instance in IIS if the application is inactive for some time the server will stop the worker process. Does Tomcat have similar behavior?
More specifically if I have a some sort of static timer, once started will it continue to run even if no requests are coming in?
I've stumbled on a topic called Tomcat Lifecycle. What is it about exactly and what benefits will I get using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Tomcat is not going to stop your app if it's not receiving requests. About the Tomcat Lifecycle, in the documentation you can find the description of the Lifecycle interface. You can implement it to customize the behaviour of your components at the start or at the stop.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html